# Continuous backup utility with several extra options

Tags: backup

I am having trouble finding proper backup utility - almost all programs recommended here or on other sites miss some feature I need to make this work for me. So what extra options I need:

1. Ability to login - NAS folder to which I want to connect is password protected
2. Ability to execute custom scripts before executing task - for example I want to stop SQL Server to be able to copy MDF files (and YES - I need to doing this way rather than using backup functionality available in SQL Server)
3. Ability to run continuous backup - so that as soon as I finish modifying some file it should go to backup location
4. Ability to set priority to backup process so that it doesn't take too much resources while I'm actively working on the laptop.
5. Easy restore & view files - I want to be able to see the files just by browsing the directory. I don't want them bundled in some app-specific file.

Comment: 3. Sounds like the most problematic. More like you need some form of replication. If you are using Windows Server you could try something like DFS-R.

Comment: You should use proper replication feature shutting down MSSQL sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: You have conflicts in your requirements.  For your non-database backups a versioning file system should work.  Your database requirements are a different beast entirely.  Applying your requirements to NAS storage makes the situation more difficult.

Comment: MSSQL I have on my box is for me only (when I develop) - so shutting it down doesn't impact anyone. And I definitely don't want to setup replication for every single database I spawn. As for "conflicting requirements" - I want just the latest version of FILES (I don't care if they are DB or picture files) so your comment is completely pointless. Anyways - guess that all this doesn't matter now that close trolls have kicked in. I've actually found a solution that's somewhat good & robust, but good luck sharing knowledge when you have idiots playing with moderation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robocopy will do ALMOST what you asking if you add it to a backup script.

SO....

1) yes, map a drive and be done.  It can use a UNC as well, but you'd need to have an active connection to the UNC with credentials for it to login without interaction (something like "net use" right before executing robocopy)

2) this is a matter of scripting.  Stop SQL, execute copy, restart SQL..  Should be easy enough with a .bat file.

3) /MON or /MOT options will work for that.  I don't prefer doing it this way.  I prefer using the task scheduler and forcing it to execute every x # of mins.  along with using the options that says to kill the process if it is still running after x minutes.

4) not really... but i doubt you'll notice it running unless your machine is really pressed for resources.  Once sync'd up, it would only copy over what has changed and not everything else.  This significantly speeds things up.

5) files are stored as they are on a the source as they are just a copy.

Comment: Yeah - that _almost_ part is what's killing me. I mean I've already played with [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155](SyncToy) and it works pretty well. Just I hate that I need to hack away things (like setting up Task Scheduler). I guess that in the end I'll go with something like Acronis Image. Anyways - thanks for proposing Robocopy and giving me more options.

Comment: And yeah for 1) just for those who don't know - you can use Control Panel -> Credential Manager to save your passwords to remote locations.

Comment: @kape123, the Task Scheduler isn't a hack IMO.  It is used by system services and even native Windows Backup as its scheduler.  The issue with something like Acronis image or Symantec Ghost is continious backup of your SQL data.  If you want a daily/hourly/scheduled backup, you would have to script it to stop and start or use a product that is SQL aware.  The file backup is easy peasy, SQL not so much (at least to do it properly).

Comment: Had another thought, if you have Previous Versions enabled, that might give you that immediate restore you are looking for and then simply schedule a nightly backup instead.  Previous Versions is a simple way to allow users to restore their files once the schedule has been setup.  Though you do need enough space to hold your Shadow Copies as they happen.